# Работа с ini файлами

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! Как сделать работу с ini файлами, чтобы была возможность создавать секции, дописывать в секции, получать все названия секций и  их значения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/)